# Can't access modem configuration centurylink

Tags: modem, wan

While rearranging my living room, I unplugged my centurylink modem/router. When plugged back in, it no longer had an internet connection. Stupid me tried to fix it, which lead to logging into the modem configuration page, going to advanced settings, WAN settings and changing from "Auto Select" to "Transparent Bridge". Once I applied the change, I lost connection to the modem and now I can't log back in. Any help would be appreciated. I spent two hours on the phone with Century Link and they couldn't help so I am ripping my hair out.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to the modem with an Ethernet cable, and then restarting your computer; or with your wired connection, open an elevated command prompt and enter:

ipconfig /release

ipconfig /renew